# Converting a GMail Label Mailbox to a Set of PDFs

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-archive

I do have a rather large task to do: I need to convert a folder in my gmail with lots of tagged messages either as a large PDF (which Adobe Acrobat does on Outlook - Except the latter crashes while loading this mailbox) or as a individual PDF (which I plan to link on a Wiki Database)

While it doesn't fully need to be in PDF (as long as I can, say, outsource to someone else to convert each .eml file as a .pdf file), I need to have them split so I can cross-reference them on a Wiki.

What would you suggest to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

i would use something like a perl script for this... i have one that goes through and gets new mail but this is something different
here's the one for new mail and modify it if you're feeling courageous

```
curl -u $1:$2 --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | \
    perl -ne 'print "\t" if //; print "$2\n" if /(.*)/;'
```

where $1 and $2 are username and password in bash argument format

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com), etc. from within Outlook or Thunderbird. Select several emails and 'print' using CutePDF. [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator), is supposed to work similarly.